# Tridion 2013 Virtual/Search Folders

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, search

Where is the documentation for Search ( Virtual Folders)? For example, I found this sample XML on stack exchange, but where is the documentation for all the various parameters?  I looked thru the official documentation, but I did not see it.

```
<SearchFolder xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/SearchFolder" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <GeneralParameters>
        <SearchQuery>TV</SearchQuery>
        <SearchIn xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:0-1-1" Recursive="true"></SearchIn>
    </GeneralParameters>
    <AdvancedParameters>
        <ItemTypes>
            <ItemType>16</ItemType>
        </ItemTypes>
        <Modified>
            <LastDays>1</LastDays>
        </Modified>
        <NumberOfItems>50</NumberOfItems>
    </AdvancedParameters>
</SearchFolder>
```

Comment: Normally you'd make Virtual Folders from an advanced search. I'm not sure for _extending_ the existing options, but for a given Virtual Search folder, you can revisit Advanced Search to change and save new settings (based on that Virtual Folder's search parameters). You'll see the item type option, modification date, and all the other options in the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the SearchFolder XML **is** considered part of the public API; it's defined in cm_searchfolder.xsd (which, in turn, is stored in CM as the SearchFolder Virtual Folder Type Schema; you will see a TypeSchema reference in the Virtual Folder itself).

Also note that the SearchFolder XML is (by design) very similar to the SearchInstruction XML, which is defined in cm_xml.xsd.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to override the search results so I can add some fields?

Comment: If you mean adding additional fields to the search result: no, that isn't possible other than creating a UI data extender which will separately retrieve the additional data. Beware of the performance impact of such a customization, though.

Answer (score 2):

From what I remember this XML is not a public API. You shouldn't build or change it manually. The reason for it is that there's a chance that it might be changed from version to version and your changes will be lost or it will not work anymore. The only valid way of getting it is by saving a search schema.